# Is it safe to delete IAM roles created automatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Amazon newbie here.

I am following along with a book on AWS and I am at the IAM chapter. I noticed that there are roles which got created automatically as I progressed through the book. I would like to ask how safe it is to delete all these roles and start fresh.

[image: Iam roles]

Comment: Those are service linked role, which some services need to operate on behalf of yourself. Why would you want to delete them?

Comment: @Victor I was trying to reduce the clutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the roles that you're showing are [service-linked roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/using-service-linked-roles.html) which essentially grant a specific service access to perform a list of operations on other resources.  For example, your Elastic Beanstalk instance in the screenshot might have a role that grants it access to write log files to a specific S3 bucket.

In general, if you delete service roles, the existing services using those roles will break.  If you're okay with that, then yes, you can delete them.

If you want to see whether a specific role has been used recently, you can:

1. Go to IAM dashboard
2. Go to "Roles"
3. Click the role you're interested in
4. Click "Access Advisor"

[image]

In the example screenshot, you can see I have a service-linked role that was last used 81 days ago, which tells me it's probably an inactive service that I don't care about anymore and I'm safe to delete the role.

All that said, a role does not cost you any money, so if you have valuable resources running in your account and are unsure if a role is in use, err on the side of caution and just leave it.

Comment: Your last line makes sense. I was trying to reduce clutter and follow a "good" policy of keeping my account clean.